# Trying to include a null value when not finding a given dictionary key

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of equipment software, and I'm trying to make a dictionary with the key being the name of the software and value an array of all versions to this key.

Equipment software list format

```py
[
    [
        {"name": "openjdk-8-jre", "version": "8u171-b11-1~deb9u1"},
        {"name": "python2.7", "version": "2.7.13"},
        {"name": "npm", "version": "8.0.0"},
    ],
    [
        {"name": "openjdk-8-jre", "version": "8u171-b11-1~deb9u1"},
    ],
    [
        {"name": "python2.7", "version": "2.7.13"},
        {"name": "npm", "version": "7.0.0"},
    ],
]
```

What I'm trying:

```py
softwares = {}

for software in all_equipment_softwares:
    softwares[software] = []

for equipment in equipments_dump:
    for software in equipment["softwares"]:
        software_name = software["name"]
        software_version = software["version"]

        softwares[software_name].append(software_version)
```

What I'm getting:

```py
[
    {"openjdk-8-jre": ["8u171-b11-1~deb9u1", "8u171-b11-1~deb9u1"]},
    {"python2.7": ["2.7.13", "2.7.13"]},
    {"npm": ["8.0.0", "7.0.0"]},
]
```

I've been trying to break my head for hours, but I can't get the expected result

The expected result:

```py
[
    {"openjdk-8-jre": ["8u171-b11-1~deb9u1", "8u171-b11-1~deb9u1", None]},
    {"python2.7": ["2.7.13", None, "2.7.13"]},
    {"npm": ["8.0.0", None, "7.0.0"]},
]
```

How can I add a null value in the values of a given key when the software is not present on that equipment?

Comment: What result are you actually getting, and why can't you fix it?

Comment: What happens when you run your code? Do you get an error? If so, what is it? Please[edit] your question to include more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach you could use to get an output with a single dictionary, instead of a list of dictionaries. The key insight is to prepopulate the value with a list of None. Feel free to ask for any clarifying questions.

```
softwares = {}
softwares_length = len(all_equipment_softwares)

#iterate through each software_list of all_equipment_softwares
for count, software_list in enumerate(all_equipment_softwares):

    #iterate through each software of software_list
    for software in software_list:

        #if it's a software we haven't seen add it to our dictionary with an array full of None based on the length of all_equipment_softwares
        if software['name'] not in softwares:
            softwares[software['name']] = [None] * softwares_length

        #update the dictionary value (the list) from None to the software version
        softwares[software['name']][count] = software['version']
print(software)
```

Output

```
{'openjdk-8-jre': ['8u171-b11-1~deb9u1', '8u171-b11-1~deb9u1', None],
'python2.7': ['2.7.13', None, '2.7.13'],
'npm': ['8.0.0', None, '7.0.0']}
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>     software_version = software["version"]
> ```

Your question was a bit vague.
I assume the above blows up with `KeyError`
when the software is not present on that equipment.

Use:

```
    software_version = software.get("version")
```

Also, please RTFM: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get